# MySQL order table by the order the rows were added

Tags: python, mysql, sql

I am moving from sqlite3 to MySQL.

When using sqlite, the default table order was by when the row was added - the newest rows at the bottom. Such as:

```
sqlite> select * from Trial_Balance;

+------------------------+--------+--------+
| General_Ledger_Account | DR     | CR     |
+------------------------+--------+--------+
| Opening Balances       |   0.00 | 200.00 |
| B1                     |   0.00 | 299.00 |
| I2                     |   0.00 |  20.00 |
| X3                     | 300.00 |   0.00 |
| TOTAL                  | 519.05 | 519.05 |
+------------------------+--------+--------+
```

When moving to MySQL, the default table order is given in alphabetical order of the 1st column:

```
mysql> select * from Trial_Balance;
+------------------------+--------+--------+
| General_Ledger_Account | DR     | CR     |
+------------------------+--------+--------+
| B1                     |   0.00 | 299.00 |
| I2                     |   0.00 |  20.00 |
| Opening Balances       |   0.00 | 200.00 |
| TOTAL                  | 519.05 | 519.05 |
| X3                     | 300.00 |   0.00 |
+------------------------+--------+--------+
```

I couldn’t find an ORDER BY which would satisfy the idea of ordering by ‘ORDER ADDED’? Does an ORDER BY ‘ORDER ADDED’ exist?

Alternatively, how would you go about achieving this? Would you create a time datatype column which automatically fills when a new entry is added, then ORDER BY this? I would appreciate an example of this in your answer.

Thanks for any help.

*My full code:*

```
def s_exe(sql):
    mycursor.execute(sql)

s_exe('''CREATE TABLE Trial_Balance
                        (General_Ledger_Account VARCHAR(20) PRIMARY KEY,
                        DR DECIMAL(13,2),
                        CR DECIMAL(13,2))''')

def tb(tb):
    mycursor.execute(("INSERT INTO Trial_Balance (General_Ledger_Account, DR, CR) VALUES (%s,%s,%s)"),((tb.General_Ledger_Account, tb.DR, tb.CR)))

def select_one(variables,tablename): #variables can be multiple e.g. 'DRcode,DR'
    mycursor.execute("SELECT {} FROM {}".format(variables,tablename))
    return mycursor.fetchone()

def create_trial_balance():
    res = select_one('SUM(DR),SUM(CR)','Opening_Balances')
    try:
        if res[0] >= res[1]: # if sum DR is greater or equal to sum CR
            tb(TB('Opening Balances','',str(res[0]-res[1])))
        else:
            tb(TB('Opening Balances',str(res[1]-res[0]),''))
    except:
        pass
    for n in return_gen_ledg_codes(): #DR and CR balances from every General Ledger
        sumDR = select_one('SUM(DR)',n)[0]
        sumCR = select_one('SUM(CR)',n)[0]
        if sumCR == None and sumDR != None:
            tb(TB(n,str(sumDR),''))
        elif sumDR == None and sumCR != None:
            tb(TB(n,'',str(sumCR)))
        elif sumDR >= sumCR:
            tb(TB(n,str(sumDR-sumCR),''))
        else:
            tb(TB(n,'',str(sumCR-sumDR)))
    try:
        res = select_one('SUM(DR),SUM(CR)','Trial_Balance') # SUM of Trial Balance
        tb(TB('TOTAL',str(res[0]),str(res[1])))          
    except:
        pass
```

Comment: There is NO any order in a table in any DBMS - the table is unordered heap. In general while quering the table server returns the records in table's clustered index order (it is easier). Always use ORDER BY if you need some definite ordering. Add auto_utilized DATETINE/TIMESTAMP `created_at` column to the table for this purposes, for example.

Comment: @Akina wouldn't a simple autoincrement `id` be another maybe simpler way

Comment: @RiggsFolly Yes, AI looks like more simple solution. But there is a reason. AI have no another meaning except ordering, whereas insertion timestamp have.